# Libgdx Audio Buffer Error

Tags: audio, libgdx, buffer

So I have being using libgdx for a while and along with that I am playing music in the game. Now the problem that has arrived is that I am getting unable to allocate audio buffer error.

So here is the detail of how I am arriving at the situation.

When the game start and the state becomes running I am setting the volume and playing the music. Also if the state changes I am changing the volume level. Now the problem arrives when if I a win the the game and then I continue, after unloading all assets when I load the assets again going into a screen it gives me `Unable to allocate audio buffers.`

So this is the problem If any body requires to see the code kindly ask for it!!

Comment: simply stop the music instead of unloading it, this could be a device specific error, Some OEM might not allow u re allocating the asset, give it a try, i am not 100% sure about it but this is first thing  that comes to my mind

Comment: i tried that, I am stopping the music and then I am unloading the manager.

Comment: try not to unload music somehow.

also check if this error comes in other devices also

Comment: check this some other person also had this same problem and reoirted to libgdx, hope it helps

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1502

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30864/problem-with-assetmanager-in-libgdx

Comment: I have already those solution but I am not hopeful about them. Anyway let me try the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is libgdx's audio class have a logic like this:

when do u calling play(); method is adding the object to an array and gives an id. When you do trying to dispose its makes the buffer null(and deletes buffer); and when you are trying to stop it its remove the object from array.

u need to keep up that lifecycle.
so just dispose it if u do not use it once more. or stop music first then dispose it.

if im wrong please correct me.

Also i just find another solution you can play the music where did u initiliaze it and pause there. And the buffer would be set. then play it where u do need. That's also works